# Use Scrapyd with arguments

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd

I'm using Scrapyd to use scrapy as webservice.

I would like to use the curl command with parameters like this :

```
curl http://myip:6800/schedule.json -d project=default -d spider=myspider -d domain=www.google.fr
```

But I don't know how to get the parameter domain in the Crawler.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MyItem(Item):
    url = Field()

class HttpbinSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "expired"
    start_urls = [domain]
```

I need to pass sometimes **one domain or multiples** in arguments.

Thank's !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible due to a missing feature in scrapy.

Users typically workaround this by serializing the arguments to curl
and then unserializing in the spider's **init**().

```
curl http://myip:6800/schedule.json -d project=default -d spider=myspider -d domains='["www1.example.com", "www2.example.com"]'
```

**Code :**

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    def __init__(self, domains=None):
        domains = json.loads(domains)
        # do something with domains...
```

Answer (score 3):

1. ```
   class YourSpider(scrapy.Spider):
       def __int__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(YourSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   ```
2. ```
   curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=somespider -d setting=DOWNLOAD_DELAY=2 -d arg1=val1
   ```
3. IN: `print(spider.arg1)` , OUT: `val1`